# Importing API credentials, stored in AWS Secrets Manager, into EC2 keeps giving errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dictionary, amazon-ec2, aws-secrets-manager

I have a Streamlit app hosted on an EC2 instance. My Twitter API credentials are stored in Secrets Manager as a dictionary with two keys: consumer_key, consumer_secret. I'm able to retrieve the whole dictionary (in the variable secret_key_1), but unable to retrieve the two keys separately, which is what I would need to do in order to collect tweets using the API. Some of the techniques I tried (each of these works on my local Jupyter notebook):

1.secret_key_1['consumer_key'], secret_key_1['consumer_secret']

2.mylist = list(secret_key_1.values()) mylist[0], mylist[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6dmy.png)

The screenshots (from the Streamlit app I'm trying to deploy) below show the errors from both methods. I've thrown the kitchen sink at this but haven't been able to resolve either of the errors. I also tried converting the dictionary to a json format, but that produces another intractable error of its own.

[First method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6dmy.png)

[Second method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VAey.png)

Comment: there is something wrong with your code, show your relevant code where you actually try to retrieve those values.

Comment: I copy-pasted the function "def get_secret()" from Secrets Manager into my code on EC2, and added a "return secret" statement at the end. I called this function from another function in my code, and checked to see if it prints as a whole dictionary (print ((secret_key_1)), which it did. After this, I'm unable to use the two separate keys of this dictionary to call the Twitter API. The code is: 

auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(secret_key_1['consumer_key'],secret_key_1['consumer_secret'])


This works well on my local notebook, & also if I import the credentials from S3,but I want to use SM.

Comment: To add to my last comment, this is what the dictionary looks like when I print it after importing it into EC2:


`{
  "consumer_key": "ABC...",
  "consumer_secret": "XYZ..."
}`

Comment: Please don't post images when you can post (cpoy and paste) text - see [ask].

Comment: @ack I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.